# Why is my C# web service not getting my JSON Array data?

Tags: asp.net, json

I am using AJAX to pass a JSON Array to a .NET web service.  The Stringified JSON array is correct when sent - I show the content in a JS alert - but when I output it within the web service, it just displays null values.

Help.

The JS is this:

```
                var listitems = [];
                $('#job-item-list').children('.iamalistitem').each(function () {
                    listitems.push({ "title": $(this).find('.job-item-title').text(), "price": $(this).find('.job-item-price').text().replace("£","").replace("&pound;","") });
                });
                alert(JSON.stringify({ ListItems: listitems }));

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ld_jobs.asmx/putJobItems",
                    // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
                    data: JSON.stringify({ ListItems : listitems }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var responseObjTwo = JSON.parse(response.d);
                        //showUserMessage(responseObjTwo.Message, false);
                        showUserMessage(response.d, false);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        var responseObj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                        showUserMessage(responseObj.Message, true);
                    }
                });
```

The receiving service is this:

```
    public class ListItem
    {
        public string itemTitle { get; set; }
        public decimal itemPrice { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string putJobItems(ListItem[] ListItems)
    {
        // Add to DB
        int errorNumber = 0;
        try
        {
            // check if on DB already
            string returnstring = "";
            errorNumber++; //1
            foreach (ListItem item in ListItems)
            {
                errorNumber++; //2,3,4
                returnstring += "Desc: " + item.itemTitle + "; Price: " + item.itemPrice.ToString() + "; ";
            }
            errorNumber++; //5
            return "{ \"Status\" : \"Success\", \"Message\" : \"Your request has been successfully posted.  Well done you.  Go put the kettle on and be lazy! \", \"input\" : \"" + returnstring + ": " + errorNumber.ToString() +  "\" }";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception newEx = new Exception("Well this is quite embarassing.  It seems the badgers have escaped! (Actual error: " + ex.Message + "; error: " + errorNumber.ToString() + ")");
            throw newEx;
        }
    }
```

The Stringyfied field going in is:

```
{"ListItems":[{"title":"(Groceries) 4 pints of milk","price":"2.00"},{"title":"(Groceries) 2 loafs of bread","price":"3.00"},{"title":"(Subway) Foot Long BMT","price":"3.00"}]}
```

Response.d comes back as:

```
{ "Status" : "Success", "Message" : "Your request has been successfully posted. Well done you. Go put the kettle on and be lazy! ", "input" : "Desc: ; Price: 0; Desc: ; Price: 0; Desc: ; Price: 0; : 5" }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: have you debug it and check that you are getting data in your listItem in web service ?

Comment: I have and the values are not there, but what I can't work out is that fact that it always has the correct number of items in the ListItem[] array, but they are all null...I can't figure out why it would not be receiving the actual data, but still have the correct number of items in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are use `title` and `price` properties names on client but `itemTitle` and `itemPrice` on server. Adjust them to use same names.

Comment: Just figured that out, as you posted!  Rookie error!  Thanks.  All working now!  ** Little Embarrassed **